# Bootstrap 4 Theme Post Layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, screen-layout

I am using Bootstrap 4 Theme in WordPress. I have moderate experience in customizing themes. The text in my Posts is left aligned within the row (appearing on the edge of the container or the web page itself). I would like the text to appear down the center of the web page. Can I centre-align the text using Custom CSS? Thanks

When I inspect the code relating to the column, it appears as follows:

```
.col-lg-8 {
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-ms-flex: 0 0 66.6666666667%;
flex: 0 0 66.6666666667%;
max-width: 66.6666666667%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. Questions related to generic css and 3rd party themes are considered off-topic on this forum. These kinds of questions might be better asked at Stack Overflow or another appropriate Stack Exchange network site. Theme questions are better asked about at their developers' support routes.

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="col-lg-8">
Your content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much. I assume this code will not go in 'Custom CSS'. Do I need to create a child theme?